How to calculate the average unique occurrences of an ID for day of the week across months in PowerPivot?
Edit. I would like to have average unique visits e.g. average all Mondays, all Tuesdays all Wednesdays in a given month. If there are  4 Tuesdays, I would like to see an average value of visit on Tuesdays in the given month.
I’m working with a PowerPivot table where:

Rows: Days of the week (e.g., Monday, Tuesday, etc.).
Columns: Year-Month combinations (e.g., 2024-11, 2024-12).
Values: I want to calculate the average number of unique occurrences of an ID for each day of the week across the selected months.

The dataset looks like this:



Date
Year_Month
Day_of_Weak
ID




2024-11-01
2024-11
Friday
A


2024-11-01
2024-11
Friday
B


2024-11-08
2024-11
Friday
A


2024-11-08
2024-11
Friday
C


2024-12-01
2024-12
Friday
B


2024-12-01
2024-12
Friday
D



I need the pivot table to look like this:



Day_of_Week
2024-11
2024-12




Monday
N/A
N/A


Tuesday
N/A
N/A


Wednesday
N/A
N/A


Thursday
N/A
N/A


Friday
3
2


Saturday
N/A
N/A


Sunday
N/A
N/A



Here:
•   For Friday in 2024-11, the unique IDs are {A, B, C} → Count = 3.
•   For Friday in 2024-12, the unique IDs are {B, D} → Count = 2.

I attempted the following DAX measure using llm at work I guess it is ChatGPT 4
=AVERAGEX(
    FILTER(
        'Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ',
        'Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ'[Day_of_Weak] = MAX('Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ'[Day_of_Weak]) &&
        'Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ'[Year_Month] = MAX('Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ'[Year_Month])
    ),
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Raport_wszystkich_wejsc_JJ'[ID])
)

However, this measure doesn’t work correctly. How can I create a measure to calculate this in PowerPivot?

you can create a day of week table. There are two columns and sort the day of week column by sort column

then create relationship between two tables

then you can get the result even don't need to create measure

make sure you select show item with no data


Simple and Direct

I am sorry I was not precise, it is about calculating average weekday (Mondays, Tuesdays.. unique visits in a month.

The output is the same as the second table in your post. If the answer is not what you want, then pls update the sample data and expected output
